# How can I bypass a load balancer

Tags: iis, load-balancing, hosts

My team deployed our sites last night, found a bug this morning, deployed again, and now all our sites are down. Our sites use a load balancer and are all running on the same IIS app pool. We've tried restarting IIS several times to no avail, which leads us to think it is a problem with the load balancer. Is it possible to bypass the load balancer using a hosts file or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network card on each server will have its own ip address, over an above the ip address published by the load balancer, you could reset your dns record to this address.

Bear in mind this'll take you down to a single server, but given that you have no servers at the moment...

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Any idea how I would find out what the IP address is for each server? And by "reset your DNS record" do you mean add it to the hosts file? Sorry for such a newbie question!

Comment: to find a machine's ip addresses - use the command "ipconfig /all" from a dos box. Somewhere in your organisation there will be a dns server which has the record "mysite = 111.222.333.444" and it the record will currently be pointing to your load balancer. ipconfig will also tell you the ip address of your dns server but not its name/location. Without at all being funny, it sounds like your top priority at the moment should be to find someone in your org who understands ip addresses and dns entries - this is really basic stuff on the infrastructure side of things

Comment: Will do that Pete, just trying to do some research. Thanks.

Comment: you could repoint each of your sites to a different server, if it helps you any as regards load. Each site will have its own dns entry (which right now will point to you lb's ip address). Pain in the ass to configure though! Hope I've helped some.

Comment: Absolutely, man. I wish I knew more about this kind of stuff. Passing the info along...